# jQuery form submition prevention not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a submit button that I am trying to intercept the data for.

I've not had trouble with this in the past but there seems to be something in this particular set up that is wrong.

I have this form:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <!--Inputs-->
    <!--...-->
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

I'm using this JS:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#myForm", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and I've tried:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#myForm", function(e){
    return false;
});
```

And both times the form still submits. I've also put in a function for serializing the form data in that event listener, and that function fires, so I know the submit event listener is working, it's just not preventing it. There are no errors in the JS console, and nothing else is behaving improperly.

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery mobile 1.4.2.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the posted code. It should prevent the submission of the form.

Comment: Is your form present on the page at the time you set the event handlers?

Comment: @undefined The second was meant to be jQuery mobile 1.4.2, fixed it.

Comment: @jcruz It is in a separate page that is brought in at the top of the JS file, then later in a `$(document).ready(function(){...}); is where the event listener resides.

Comment: if you can't identify the issue, try using _button_

<input type="button" value="Search">

Comment: Doesn't matter, the document is always available, so DOM ready is not an issue. As said in the first comment, there's nothing wrong with what you've posted, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @adeneo Then I obviously have something wrong somewhere in my JS...

Comment: @rrkwells I may end up having to fall back to that. Thanks.

Comment: Well, yes! Something is obviously wrong, there's just nothing wrong with what you've posted. Are you sure the ID's match and that there's no errors in the console.

Comment: @adeneo The IDs match, I even copy pasted them, and there is one error but it's a 404 from a missing image.at 2000+ lines I'm not eager to start debugging the JS, I'll probably just switch to a button click listener...